# Convert 2012-06-28T14:30:00-04:00 to yyyyMMddTHHmm format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, iso8601

I want to convert a date in c# like 2012-06-28T14:30:00-04:00 in to "yyyyMMddTHHmm" format both dates are in string.

```
string currentDate="2012-06-28T14:30:00-04:00";
string requiredDate="yyyyMMddTHHmm"
```

When i am trying to convert this date with Convert.ToDateTime() then C# return "20120629T0000-04:00" but this is not correct date.

Comment: Look into DateTime.ToString() method

Comment: I think that T could be the problem. You can take a look at Custom date format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4

Comment: I tried this but didn't find any help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) (MSDN). I guess it might be enough to use just the `ToString()` method on your `DateTime` instances.

Possibly you might need to specify `CultureInfo` (MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) in the appropriate overloads of the convert methods. Possibly the server and client applications are in different cultures and/or timezones.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse("2012-06-28T14:30:00-04:00").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm")` produces value you may want.

Note that changing value from absolute ISO8601 format to local ISO8601 format should be done carefully as it changes meaning of the value and often value itself.

Please make sure which of the following options you really want (and adjust code accordingly):

- simply drop time from the value. Will produce semi-random time if values are coming from different time-zones.
- always move value to a given timezone and make it local to that timezone.
- always move value to current timezone and make it local to current timezone

Or maybe you are looking for something else altogether.

Comment: No dear i tried this,but i am getting 20120629T0000 , which is a wrong date. i need 20120628T1430 or 20120628T0230

Comment: @Ramesh, "Wrong date" is not a good explanation, especially if you offer 2 different values as "correct". Please read and comment on line of my answer "...following options you really want".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the format you are trying out

```
string currentDate="2012-06-28T14:30:00-04:00";
DateTime.Parse(currentDate).ToString("o")
```

This will give you `2012-06-29T00:00:00.0000000+05:30`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this, but this is not correct as i need 20120628T14:30 only but it is giving me 29 which is incorrect date.